# file_get_contents() を使ってGoogleのAPIからデータを取得出来ない

Tags: php

例えばPHP 5.4.39で以下の様なコードを実行すると

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=');
var_dump($data);
```

期待している動作では、以下のjsonが返ってくると思っています。

```
{
 "error": "invalid_token",
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

ところが、`bool(false)`となりデータが取得出来ません。
ブラウザでアクセスした場合は問題がありません。
試しにUser-Agentを指定した場合でも挙動に変化はありませんでした。

ちなみに

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.co.jp/');
```

とした場合には、問題無くHTMLが取得出来ております。

対応方法としては`cURL`で実装すれば問題無いことはわかっていますが、
なぜ`file_get_contents()`で出来ないのか知りたいところです。
恐らくGoogleの場合だけこの問題が発生しております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ブラウザでアクセスした場合は問題がありません。

ブラウザでアクセスした場合もhttp statusは400で返ってきてると思います。 
file_get_contents() は既定値では http statusが400番台500番台のときはコンテンツを取得しません。 
以下のようにすることでエラー時もコンテンツを取得するようになります。

```
$opt = array("http" => array('ignore_errors' => true));
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=', false, stream_context_create($opt));
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
無事解決出来ました。